# Existe alguna forma de eliminar if repetitivos en python?

Tags: python

Existe alguna manera de optimizar el siguiente código para disminuir las líneas y no usar tanto **if?** o algo mas **eficiente o profesional** ya que tendría que usar funciones parecidas para muchos mas casos en las validaciones de dataframes y el código queda muy largo gracias por su ayuda.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
        
data = io.StringIO("""
                   ID     EDUCATIVO
                   132133     Basica_Primaria
                   132133     Basica_Secundaria
                   132133     Profesional
                   132133     Doctorado
                   132133     Media_Academica_o_Clasica
                   132133     Maestria
                   132133     Normalista                  
                   """)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")

def educativo(row):
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Media_Academica_o_Clasica":
            return 4
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Basica_Secundaria":
            return 3
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Tecnica_Profesional":
            return 7   
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Basica_Primaria":
            return 2
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Media_Tecnica_(Bachillerato Tecnico)":
            return 5
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Profesional":
            return 9
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Tecnologica":
            return 8
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Preescolar":
            return 1   
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Doctorado":
            return 12
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Maestria":
            return 11
        if row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Especializacion":
            return 10
        elif row["EDUCATIVO"] == "Normalista":
            return 6 
        else:
            return 13
    
df = df.assign(educativo_validado=df.apply(educativo, axis=1))# llamo a función educativo
df
```

Resultado que se extrae del código ejecutado

```
ID  EDUCATIVO   educativo_validado
0   132133  Basica_Primaria 2
1   132133  Basica_Secundaria   3
2   132133  Profesional 9
3   132133  Doctorado   12
4   132133  Media_Academica_o_Clasica   4
5   132133  Maestria    11
6   132133  Normalista  6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un diccionario indexado por el "educativo" y que devuelva el valor entero asociado:

```
tabla = {
    "Media_Academica_o_Clasica": 4,
    "Basica_Secundaria":       3,
    "Tecnica_Profesional":        7,
    "Basica_Primaria":        2,
    "Media_Tecnica_(Bachillerato Tecnico)":        5,
    "Profesional":        9,
    "Tecnologica":        8,
    "Preescolar":        1,
    "Doctorado":        12,
    "Maestria":        11,
    "Especializacion":        10,
    "Normalista":        6
}
```

con lo cual puedes retornar el nivel educativo simplemente usando la clase:

```
print(tabla["Normalista"]) => 6
```

Con eso la función se reduce a:

```
def educativo(row):

    if row["EDUCATIVO"] in tabla:
        return tabla[row["EDUCATIVO"]]

    return 13
```

Si el `educativo` ("Profesional", "Doctorado", etc.) esta en la tabla, devuelve el valor asignado. Si no, devuelve 13.

Comment: Gracias muy util